# Margin bot after resize image with MotionScene

Tags: android, android-motionlayout

I am doing a example with MotionLayout, I just want resize a image when I do scroll. The problem is when the animation finish the bottom margin is biger than before the animation. How can I solve it and get the same margin at start and end animation.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/PPslk.jpg "before"

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZU9oK.jpg "after"

```
<MotionScene
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:motion="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<Transition
        motion:constraintSetEnd="@+id/end"
        motion:constraintSetStart="@+id/start"
        motion:duration="1000"
        motion:motionInterpolator="linear">

    <OnSwipe
            motion:touchAnchorId="@+id/llcontainer"
            motion:touchAnchorSide="bottom"
            motion:dragDirection="dragUp"/>
</Transition>
<ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/start"/>
<ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/end">
    <Constraint
            android:id="@id/card_img"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"/>
</ConstraintSet>
```

```
<android.support.constraint.motion.MotionLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:showPaths="false"
    app:layoutDescription="@xml/card_motion"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/card_img"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="227dp"
        android:src="@drawable/mario"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:foregroundGravity="center_vertical"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/llcontainer" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="400dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/llcontainer"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/card_img"/>

</android.support.constraint.motion.MotionLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

try android:layout_height="match_parent" or android:layout_height="wrap_content"